# Angular 2 Component Styles not resolving css imports from node_modules

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Based on the documentation found under [Angular Component Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html), I was trying to import the style sheets found under the node_modules; ie:

test.component.css:

`@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme.css';`

Whereby the component is defined:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['test.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TestComponent {
}
```

Unfortunately when browsed to the page, it comes up that the ~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme.css cannot be found.

This project was set up using the Angular-Cli.

I suppose I could copy in the styles, and reference them that way, but I'd rather keep the library dependencies separate.

Comment: Just to make sure , did you install @angular/material . Is the folder structure correct and file exists in node_modules

Comment: This looks resolved once I upgraded from angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.28.3 to angular/cli v1.1.2.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include any style sheet from node module folder.. you just need to add it in .angular-cli.json

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
]
```

Also you don't need to add `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` until you are creating your html dynamically with some third party plugin or adding some random css.

you can always use global css which are included in your .angular-cli.json

Comment: That's correct. You can also import the style in styles.css

Comment: It looks like upgrading to a angular-cli v1.1.2 fixed it without needing to modify the .angular-cli.json though I did try that too.  I still find that I need to use ViewEncapsulation.None otherwise the classes that are imported are not being resolved when I add them to the element's classList.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the file extension. You are using the extension `css` which doesn't support to import file from the other location better way you can change the extension to the `scss`. In this you can import the files from the `node_modules`.

Comment: CSS import not supported ?

Comment: In webpack when css import any file it is interpreted as the URL and if you use the scss then the file is imported as `style-loader`. Means it actually load the file not just URL.